# WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 How can get all users in An Active Directory and Insert to Identity Server Users?

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an Active Directory with 10 users.
I want get all users to Identity server users.
How can Do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should create a user store
2. you should connect to active directory with user admin and password
3. you should have a LDAP on your AD server
4. port 389 should open to your IS server
5. then you can see all user in users section
   all of this steps available in this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhkwN8tr41k

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. Bulk import users(Refer [1]): Get the users in AD to CSV/Excel file and import it to IS
2. Use JIT provisioning: Connect AD as federated IdP[2][3] in wso2 is and use JIT[4] provisioning to provision the users when they are login into IS. You can use silent provisioning for simplicity

[1]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-users/#importing-users
[2]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycIplHrB6a4&ab_channel=WSO2
[3]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-read-write-active-directory-user-store/
[4]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-just-in-time-provisioning-for-an-identity-provider/